# Aggregating percentage for one column by categories in another column in R

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate, plyr

I know this is basic but I'm having issues with it. I have taken this sample data from:

[Link to article containing sample data](https://www.computerworld.com/article/2486425/business-intelligence/business-intelligence-4-data-wrangling-tasks-in-r-for-advanced-beginners.html)

```
companiesData <- data.frame(fy = c(2010,2011,2012,2010,2011,2012,2010,2011,2012),
                            company = c("Apple","Apple","Apple","Google","Google","Google",
                                        "Microsoft","Microsoft","Microsoft"),
                            revenue = c(65225,108249,156508,29321,37905,50175,
                                        62484,69943,73723), 
                            profit = c(14013,25922,41733,8505,9737,10737,
                                       18760,23150,16978))
```

How would I find the percentage profit for each company for each year? An example would be adding all the profits for Apple and then the percentage of this sum for each apple row as appropriate. The end results should be a table with all columns but only aggregated by company using percentage profit. The years remain the same.
The answer will be 17.16% for the first row of Apple and is calculated by:

```
(14013/81668)*100
```

Where 81668 is the total for apple and 17.16% is the percentage profit for the first row of Apple which is for 2010. I don't want this done as a time series as the variable may not necessarily be time. It could be location.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50124465/edit) your question to include the expected output for your sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using base r:

```
fun=function(x)paste0(round(x/sum(x)*100,2),"%")
transform(companiesData,prec=ave(profit,company,FUN=fun))
    fy   company revenue profit   prec
1 2010     Apple   65225  14013 17.16%
2 2011     Apple  108249  25922 31.74%
3 2012     Apple  156508  41733  51.1%
4 2010    Google   29321   8505 29.35%
5 2011    Google   37905   9737  33.6%
6 2012    Google   50175  10737 37.05%
7 2010 Microsoft   62484  18760 31.86%
8 2011 Microsoft   69943  23150 39.31%
9 2012 Microsoft   73723  16978 28.83%


library(data.table)
setDT(companiesData)[,prec:=profit/sum(profit)*100,by=company][]
     fy   company revenue profit     prec
1: 2010     Apple   65225  14013 17.15850
2: 2011     Apple  108249  25922 31.74071
3: 2012     Apple  156508  41733 51.10080
4: 2010    Google   29321   8505 29.34884
5: 2011    Google   37905   9737 33.60019
6: 2012    Google   50175  10737 37.05097
7: 2010 Microsoft   62484  18760 31.85708
8: 2011 Microsoft   69943  23150 39.31191
9: 2012 Microsoft   73723  16978 28.83100
```

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr` solution: group by company, add up all that company's profits, then create a new variable of the share of each year's profits over the total profits.

```r
library(dplyr)

# delete reading in data from OP

companiesData %>%
    group_by(company) %>%
    mutate(total_profit = sum(profit)) %>%
    mutate(share_this_yr = profit / total_profit)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 6
#> # Groups:   company [3]
#>      fy company   revenue profit total_profit share_this_yr
#>   <dbl> <fct>       <dbl>  <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>
#> 1  2010 Apple       65225  14013        81668         0.172
#> 2  2011 Apple      108249  25922        81668         0.317
#> 3  2012 Apple      156508  41733        81668         0.511
#> 4  2010 Google      29321   8505        28979         0.293
#> 5  2011 Google      37905   9737        28979         0.336
#> 6  2012 Google      50175  10737        28979         0.371
#> 7  2010 Microsoft   62484  18760        58888         0.319
#> 8  2011 Microsoft   69943  23150        58888         0.393
#> 9  2012 Microsoft   73723  16978        58888         0.288
```

Created on 2018-05-01 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).